# Operation aborted when calling ReadValueAsync()

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I have a Bluetooth Low Energy (BluetoothLE) device that sends a value to my C++ WinRT BluetoothLE tool after it receives a specific value. Everything works perfectly when the device is turned on and connected. However, when I turn off my device, I encounter an `Operation aborted exception`. I understand that this is entirely expected since the device is no longer connected, but I'm struggling to catch that exception. I tried to catch the exeption with `catch(...) {}` but without success. When I am using `BluetoothCacheMode::Cached` instead of `BluetoothCacheMode::Uncached` as parameter, I don't receive any exceptions. However, the value I receive is incorrect.

Here is the source code of my readMessage function:

```
Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<bool> BluetoothLEDeviceDisplay::readData()
{
    auto lifetime = get_strong();

    if (characteristic) 
    {
        GattReadResult result = { nullptr };
            
        if (IsConnected()) 
        {
            try 
            {
                result = co_await characteristic.ReadValueAsync(BluetoothCacheMode::Uncached);
            }
            catch (...) 
            {
                    LogMessage(L"Could not read something");
            }
            if (result.Status() == GattCommunicationStatus::Success)
            {
                LogMessage(L"Read something");
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the thread-method where I am calling the previous method:

```
fire_and_forget BluetoothLEDeviceDisplay::manageBluetoothConnection()
{
    auto lifetime = get_strong();      

    while (true) 
    {

        if (!IsConnected()) 
        {
            auto processOp{ Connect() };
            processOp.get();
        }


        if (IsConnected()) 
        {
            auto processOp{ SendData(L"3") };
            processOp.get();                            
        }

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
        readData();
            
    }
}
```

I am a beginner at c++-winrt and BluetoothLE, so I could not find a solution yet. If someone could help me I would be very thankfull.

Thanks!

Comment: *"I tried to catch the ex\[c\]eption with `catch(...) {}` but without success."* - That looks like the correct thing to do. C++/WinRT translates `HRESULT` error codes into C++ exceptions, and C++ exceptions are re-thrown on the thread that initiated the asynchronous operation. How, exactly, does this fail?

Comment: I see the problem now: `catch(...) {}` swallows the C++ exception. The code then moves on to access `result` (still default-initialized), causing an access violation. Does that coincide with your observations?

Comment: Yes, I am also getting an access violation. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes. You'll have to arrange that a failed `ReadValueAsync()` call never reaches the code that accesses the return value (`result`) that was never populated. You can do so by re-trowing the exception (`throw;`) and having client code deal with failures reported through C++ exceptions. Alternatively, have `readData()` return a `std::optional<bool>`, allowing clients to observe the outcome without getting C++ exceptions involved. (I haven't verified whether `IAsyncOperation` can carry a `std::optional` payload.)